# paginate manually after paginate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to sort pictures by like and paginate them .

Like has a table with : `pic_id ,user_id`

`pic_id` is the id of the picture 
and user_id is the id of the user who liked the picture.

in $sort we have  `pic_id` and `count` which is count of likes.

Now, the problem are pictures with 0 likes, which are not adding in $pic

any solution?

```
public function sort()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $sort=DB::table('likes')
         ->select('pic_id',DB::raw('count(pic_id) as count'))
         ->groupBy('pic_id')
         ->orderBy('count','desc')
         ->paginate(3);

    $pic_id=collect($sort->items())->pluck('pic_id')->toArray();
    $pic=Picture::whereIn('id',$pic_id)
                 ->with('user')
                ->get();

    $data=new LengthAwarePaginator($pic,$sort->total(),$sort->perPage(),$sort->currentPage());
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```